# EXCEPTION: Template parse errors in angular 2.0 behaving differently

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular

A sample application in angular 2.0 using typescript is working perfectly in plnker ([Link Here](http://plnkr.co/edit/5FF2WRjaFautvzcYWzC6?p=preview)). But when the same thing is running using VS 2013, I am getting an error like below

```
EXCEPTION: Template parse errors:
Can't bind to 'ngmodel' since it isn't a known native property ("<label>Name:</label>
<input  [ERROR ->][(ngmodel)]="yourname" placeholder="Enter a name here">
<hr>
<h1 [hidden]="!yourname">Hello {{yourname}}!</h1>
"): HelloWorld@1:8
```

If I remove `[(ngmodel)]="yourname"` I am getting the HTML page atleast. Can anyone help with this??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `ngModel` instead of `ngmodel`:

```
<input [(ngModel)]="yourname" placeholder="Enter a name here">
```